# Why Mysql is returning wrong count of rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have in database two information that matches with the names and the address. Instead of returning 2, this code is returning 21. Please see below;
(Table)-employees
id
name
address

```
$select = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE name LIKE '%John%' 
    OR name LIKE '%Johanson%' 
   AND address='Streetford End'
   ");
$count = mysql_num_rows($select);
echo $count
```

Comment: Well, did you look at the data returned?

Comment: You have a typo. You need parentheses

Comment: I think it should be `address LIKE 'Streetford End'`

Comment: @MilanGupta `LIKE` without `%` is same as `address = "Streetford End"`

Comment: You need to show us the rows in your database. Also, have you tried this in command line mysql to make sure it works first?

Comment: Is your code working in MySQL and not working as expected in PHP or are you just assuming it should work in reality the same way you think it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE (name LIKE '%John%' OR name LIKE '%Johanson%')
  AND address='Streetford End'
```

Comment: @BeetleJuice, May i know what's the amendments you made in my answer ?

Comment: Also @K.Wayne, please let me know if my answer is helpful to you ?

Comment: @KartikShah I put your code inside a code block. I didn't change any content :-)